# Slave interface receiving packets but not bond. Why?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bonding, interface, icmp, slave

I have 2 network interfaces with mac **aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa** and **bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb** 
When i bind them the bond gets the mac aa:aa:aa:aa:aa. I make a configuration where i make sure all the replies of icmp requests leaving the bond reaches the bond ip at the **bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb** interface. I can see the replies coming in the above slave interface but not in the bond. I am using wireshark to monitor the packets. Shouldnt this thing work?

Also the request packets are leaving though **aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa** since **bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb** has no connection to the router.

Comment: Bond can work in several modes. What mode do you use?

Comment: mode 6. adaptive load balancing

Comment: Physical interfaces must be available to change their mac-addresses at mode 6. What OS do you have on server?

Comment: For now im just trying to ping my router

Comment: Eh wait. I can some replies coming to the bond interface in wireshark. yet no replies in the command window